# RxSwift - Why wrap ControlProperty trait into a Driver?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

In the official RxSwift [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md#driver), it's described that traits `Driver` and `ControlProperty` share many similarities between them (can't error out, observe occurs on main scheduler, share and replay side effects), but at the same time in the example provided `ControlProperty` `rx.text` is being wrapped into a Driver.

So the questions would be:

- Is there any real advantage of wrapping a `ControlProperty` into a `Driver` trait?
- If both `ControlProperty` and `Driver` are supposed to share and replay by default, why is `.share(replay: 1)` operator being called in the first code but not in the second?

Here I attach the referenced code from the documentation:

**From:**

```swift
let results = query.rx.text
    .throttle(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .flatMapLatest { query in
        fetchAutoCompleteItems(query)
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)  // results are returned on MainScheduler
            .catchErrorJustReturn([])           // in the worst case, errors are handled
    }
    .share(replay: 1)                           // HTTP requests are shared and results replayed
                                                // to all UI elements

results
    .map { "\($0.count)" }
    .bind(to: resultCount.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

results
    .bind(to: resultsTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell")) { (_, result, cell) in
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(result)"
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**To:**

```swift
let results = query.rx.text.asDriver()        // This converts a normal sequence into a `Driver` sequence.
    .throttle(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .flatMapLatest { query in
        fetchAutoCompleteItems(query)
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])  // Builder just needs info about what to return in case of error.
    }

results
    .map { "\($0.count)" }
    .drive(resultCount.rx.text)               // If there is a `drive` method available instead of `bind(to:)`,
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)              // that means that the compiler has proven that all properties
                                              // are satisfied.
results
    .drive(resultsTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell")) { (_, result, cell) in
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(result)"
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, the `throttle` that is used returns an Observable.

In the second example, because of the `asDriver()` call, a different `throttle` is used that returns a Driver (i.e., a `SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, String>`)

Your confusion likely stems from the fact that there are two `throttle` functions in the RxSwift library. One is an extension on ObservableType (ControlProperty is an extension of ObservableType) whereas the other is an extension on `SharedSequenceConvertibleType` (Driver is an extension of that.)